# Operation Protective Edge and My Brothers Keeper

Tags: army-military-war, current-events, state-of-israel, rabbis

In light of current events are there what are the halachic resolutions surrounding Operation Protective Edge and Operation My Brother's Keeper?

Issues include:

- firing at legitimate targets if it is likely that civilians will be killed
- the issues of a 'proportionate' response
- whether this is a milchemet mitzvah
- detaining scores of prisoners to find the culprits of a murder
- endangering the lives of soldiers in a ground offensive in order to secure lasting protection for the people

Please feel free to comment on other issues that are halachically relevant to the current operations carried out by Israel.

Comment: Is being hotly debated where?

Comment: Please explain the down vote? All media outlets are debating the issue. Religious parties as well as religious members of Knesset are split on what the correct strategies are. It is a legitimate question to ask what the religious response to this operation is.

Comment: Why should one expect that there is a halachic/hashkafic stance on this operation any more, less or different from any other operation in the past? Is there a basis for debate and comment that is unique to this operation?

Comment: @Danno you could ask that question about any incident in history. Firstly, it is interesting to hear what gedolim have to say about current issues to see how they apply the halacha. Secondly, I was going to write a more general question but it would go against the policy of this forum, being beyond the scope of debate. This is current and narrow enough to debate issues such as firing at legitimate targets 'protected' by civilians and there is always an interesting interplay between religion and state, etc.

Comment: edited for further clarity...

Comment: Many of these questions have little to do with each other. (e.g. the fourth and fifth)